# Detecting looping behavior in track data

Tags: r

I've got some unusual track data. Instead of trying to track wild animal behavior, this is the path a human travels while collecting some sensor readings. When they reach a particular point of interest along their transect, they walk around it in a circle. We want to extract the sensor readings from that loop separately from the whole track. I haven't included the sensor readings in my example data below for brevity, but I have many of these datasets, so visual inspection is out. If I can figure out how to identify the cluster associated with looping back and crossing their own path, I'll be set. I don't know if there are standard algorithms for finding this sort of thing, so I tried 3 naive approaches:

1. Looking just at the density of points, under the assumption that looping back instead of walking across a linear path will generate a high-density area. This didn't work at all.
2. Looking at the distances covered by an *N*-point stretch along the track, and then finding the rolling minima within that new time series. My thinking here was that the act of looping back on yourself would result in short distances compared to the more linear behavior. This is overly sensitive and too dependent on finding the right window sizes.
3. Look at the change in heading as the person is walking, since they're proceeding in a more or less linear fashion. Finding where the heading jumps from -180 to 180 (or vice versa). This **seems** to work, but I feel like I don't have the logic quite right.

Is there an established algorithm for finding this kind of feature? Am I getting anywhere with approach 3?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)
# library(MASS)
# library(RcppRoll)
# library(geosphere)

# Example data
anon_track <- structure(
  list(
    ts = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
           10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
           23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
           36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
           49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 
           62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 
           75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
           88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
           101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
           112L, 113L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
           113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 
           124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 
           135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 
           146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
           157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 
           168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 
           179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 
           190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 
           201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 
           212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 
           223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 
           234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 
           245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 
           256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 
           267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 
           278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 
           289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 
           300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 
           311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 
           322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 
           333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 
           344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 
           355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 
           366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 
           377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 386L, 387L, 
           388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 
           399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 
           410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 
           421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 431L, 
           432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 442L, 
           443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 
           454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 
           465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 474L, 475L, 
           476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 486L, 
           487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 
           498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 
           509L, 510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 518L, 519L, 
           520L, 521L, 522L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 
           531L, 532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 541L, 
           542L, 543L, 544L, 545L, 546L, 547L, 548L, 549L, 550L, 551L, 552L, 
           553L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 560L, 561L, 562L, 563L, 
           564L, 565L, 566L, 567L, 568L, 569L, 570L, 571L, 572L, 573L, 574L, 
           575L, 576L, 577L, 578L, 579L, 580L, 581L, 582L, 583L, 584L, 585L, 
           586L, 587L, 588L, 589L, 590L, 591L, 592L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 
           597L, 598L, 599L, 600L, 601L, 602L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 606L, 607L, 
           608L, 609L, 610L, 611L, 612L, 613L, 614L, 615L, 616L, 617L, 618L, 
           619L, 620L, 621L, 622L, 623L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L, 
           630L, 631L, 632L, 633L, 634L, 635L, 636L, 637L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 
           641L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 
           652L, 653L, 654L, 655L, 656L, 657L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 661L, 662L, 
           663L, 664L, 665L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 671L, 672L, 673L, 
           674L, 675L, 676L, 677L, 678L, 679L, 680L, 681L, 682L, 683L, 684L, 
           685L, 686L, 687L, 688L, 689L, 690L, 691L, 692L, 693L, 694L, 695L, 
           696L, 697L, 698L, 699L, 700L, 701L, 702L, 703L, 704L, 705L, 706L, 
           707L, 708L, 709L, 710L, 711L, 712L, 713L, 714L, 715L, 716L, 717L
    ), 
    lng = c(0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.64187717, 
            0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.6418775, 0.64187733, 
            0.64187733, 0.64187717, 0.641877, 0.641877, 0.64187633, 0.6418755, 
            0.64187533, 0.64187533, 0.64187517, 0.64187567, 0.64187617, 0.64187717, 
            0.64187817, 0.64187917, 0.64188033, 0.64188167, 0.64188317, 0.6418845, 
            0.641886, 0.64188767, 0.64188933, 0.64189067, 0.64189217, 0.64189367, 
            0.6418955, 0.64189783, 0.64189967, 0.64190217, 0.6419045, 0.64190683, 
            0.64190867, 0.64191083, 0.64191283, 0.64191467, 0.641917, 0.64191917, 
            0.641921, 0.64192267, 0.6419245, 0.641927, 0.64192917, 0.641931, 
            0.641933, 0.64193433, 0.64193567, 0.64193683, 0.6419385, 0.6419405, 
            0.64194283, 0.64194517, 0.641947, 0.641949, 0.64195083, 0.64195233, 
            0.64195333, 0.641955, 0.64195717, 0.6419595, 0.64196167, 0.64196417, 
            0.641966, 0.641968, 0.64196983, 0.6419725, 0.64197417, 0.641976, 
            0.64197733, 0.641979, 0.64198033, 0.6419825, 0.64198533, 0.64198733, 
            0.64198933, 0.64199083, 0.64199233, 0.64199333, 0.64199483, 0.64199667, 
            0.64199883, 0.6420005, 0.64200267, 0.64200483, 0.642007, 0.64200933, 
            0.6420115, 0.64201367, 0.64201533, 0.64201683, 0.64201833, 0.64201967, 
            0.64202133, 0.64202317, 0.64202467, 0.6420265, 0.64202867, 0.64203017, 
            0.64203167, 0.64203333, 0.642035, 0.6420365, 0.64203817, 0.64204033, 
            0.64204217, 0.64204383, 0.6420455, 0.64204833, 0.642051, 0.64205333, 
            0.64205517, 0.64205717, 0.64205867, 0.64206017, 0.64206233, 0.64206517, 
            0.642068, 0.6420705, 0.64207283, 0.64207483, 0.642077, 0.64207933, 
            0.642082, 0.64208417, 0.64208633, 0.64208867, 0.64209083, 0.64209267, 
            0.64209517, 0.64209767, 0.6421, 0.64210217, 0.642104, 0.64210583, 
            0.64210783, 0.64211017, 0.6421125, 0.6421145, 0.64211683, 0.6421185, 
            0.642121, 0.64212317, 0.64212617, 0.64212783, 0.64213033, 0.64213217, 
            0.64213383, 0.6421345, 0.642136, 0.642138, 0.64214033, 0.64214167, 
            0.64214317, 0.64214433, 0.64214567, 0.64214717, 0.64214917, 0.64215117, 
            0.6421535, 0.64215583, 0.642158, 0.64216033, 0.64216217, 0.64216483, 
            0.64216633, 0.64216833, 0.64217067, 0.64217367, 0.64217533, 0.64217767, 
            0.6421795, 0.64218133, 0.64218233, 0.6421835, 0.6421845, 0.6421865, 
            0.6421885, 0.64219083, 0.6421925, 0.64219367, 0.64219533, 0.64219767, 
            0.64219967, 0.64220183, 0.64220467, 0.6422075, 0.64220917, 0.64221117, 
            0.642213, 0.64221467, 0.64221683, 0.6422195, 0.64222233, 0.64222433, 
            0.6422265, 0.6422285, 0.64223033, 0.64223317, 0.6422355, 0.64223717, 
            0.642239, 0.64224067, 0.6422415, 0.6422425, 0.642244, 0.64224617, 
            0.64224783, 0.6422495, 0.64225117, 0.64225317, 0.6422545, 0.64225617, 
            0.64225817, 0.64226067, 0.64226233, 0.64226383, 0.64226517, 0.6422665, 
            0.6422675, 0.642268, 0.64226967, 0.6422715, 0.6422735, 0.64227533, 
            0.64227733, 0.64227917, 0.64228083, 0.6422825, 0.642285, 0.64228767, 
            0.64228917, 0.64229083, 0.6422925, 0.642294, 0.6422955, 0.64229783, 
            0.64230067, 0.642303, 0.6423045, 0.64230617, 0.64230783, 0.64230917, 
            0.64231033, 0.642312, 0.64231383, 0.64231533, 0.642317, 0.6423185, 
            0.64231983, 0.64232067, 0.64232117, 0.64232167, 0.642322, 0.642323, 
            0.64232367, 0.6423245, 0.64232583, 0.6423265, 0.64232683, 0.64232667, 
            0.64232667, 0.642327, 0.642328, 0.64232917, 0.642331, 0.6423325, 
            0.64233333, 0.6423335, 0.64233333, 0.642333, 0.64233383, 0.64233467, 
            0.64233633, 0.64233817, 0.64234033, 0.6423415, 0.6423425, 0.64234317, 
            0.64234383, 0.64234417, 0.6423455, 0.6423475, 0.64234933, 0.64235083, 
            0.64235183, 0.642353, 0.642354, 0.64235517, 0.642356, 0.64235733, 
            0.64235933, 0.64236133, 0.642363, 0.64236433, 0.6423655, 0.64236617, 
            0.64236667, 0.642367, 0.6423675, 0.64236833, 0.64236933, 0.64237067, 
            0.64237183, 0.64237267, 0.64237317, 0.642373, 0.64237283, 0.64237233, 
            0.64237283, 0.64237317, 0.6423735, 0.64237317, 0.64237283, 0.64237233, 
            0.64237133, 0.6423715, 0.6423715, 0.64237183, 0.64237133, 0.64237117, 
            0.64237033, 0.6423695, 0.64236833, 0.64236733, 0.64236633, 0.6423655, 
            0.64236433, 0.64236283, 0.64236083, 0.6423585, 0.642357, 0.64235533, 
            0.64235417, 0.64235267, 0.642351, 0.64234933, 0.64234767, 0.64234667, 
            0.64234567, 0.6423445, 0.64234367, 0.64234267, 0.642342, 0.64234133, 
            0.64234083, 0.64234, 0.64233933, 0.64233867, 0.64233817, 0.6423375, 
            0.6423375, 0.64233767, 0.64233733, 0.64233733, 0.64233683, 0.64233683, 
            0.642337, 0.64233817, 0.6423395, 0.64234033, 0.64234017, 0.64234067, 
            0.642341, 0.64234083, 0.64234083, 0.64234117, 0.64234267, 0.6423435, 
            0.6423445, 0.64234567, 0.6423465, 0.64234767, 0.64234983, 0.6423515, 
            0.64235267, 0.64235383, 0.64235533, 0.642356, 0.642357, 0.64235817, 
            0.64235967, 0.64236083, 0.64236217, 0.64236433, 0.64236717, 0.6423695, 
            0.64237167, 0.64237417, 0.64237667, 0.6423785, 0.64238017, 0.64238183, 
            0.64238333, 0.6423855, 0.64238767, 0.64239017, 0.642392, 0.64239367, 
            0.6423945, 0.642396, 0.64239667, 0.64239867, 0.642401, 0.64240283, 
            0.64240417, 0.64240567, 0.64240767, 0.64240917, 0.642411, 0.64241267, 
            0.64241417, 0.6424155, 0.6424175, 0.642419, 0.64242, 0.64242167, 
            0.64242383, 0.6424265, 0.64242867, 0.642431, 0.6424335, 0.64243567, 
            0.64243767, 0.64244, 0.642442, 0.64244433, 0.64244583, 0.642447, 
            0.64244733, 0.6424485, 0.64245033, 0.64245283, 0.64245433, 0.64245617, 
            0.64245783, 0.64245967, 0.642461, 0.64246283, 0.642465, 0.64246733, 
            0.64246933, 0.64247083, 0.64247233, 0.64247383, 0.64247533, 0.64247733, 
            0.64247967, 0.6424815, 0.64248317, 0.64248467, 0.6424865, 0.64248833, 
            0.642491, 0.642493, 0.64249433, 0.64249567, 0.64249733, 0.6424985, 
            0.6425005, 0.642503, 0.64250583, 0.642508, 0.64251, 0.6425115, 
            0.64251333, 0.64251483, 0.64251717, 0.64252017, 0.64252233, 0.64252417, 
            0.64252617, 0.64252833, 0.64253017, 0.64253233, 0.642535, 0.64253717, 
            0.64253883, 0.64254067, 0.64254267, 0.642545, 0.64254683, 0.64254917, 
            0.6425515, 0.64255283, 0.6425545, 0.642556, 0.64255767, 0.64255917, 
            0.64256117, 0.642563, 0.64256467, 0.64256633, 0.64256817, 0.64257, 
            0.6425715, 0.6425735, 0.64257583, 0.64257733, 0.64257883, 0.64258083, 
            0.64258267, 0.64258467, 0.64258733, 0.64258917, 0.64259083, 0.64259233, 
            0.642594, 0.64259517, 0.64259683, 0.64259917, 0.642601, 0.64260267, 
            0.642604, 0.64260517, 0.6426065, 0.6426075, 0.6426095, 0.642612, 
            0.64261467, 0.64261667, 0.64261833, 0.64262, 0.6426215, 0.64262333, 
            0.64262567, 0.6426285, 0.6426305, 0.6426325, 0.64263383, 0.64263583, 
            0.64263783, 0.6426405, 0.64264333, 0.64264517, 0.64264667, 0.64264767, 
            0.64264883, 0.64265, 0.64265167, 0.64265367, 0.642655, 0.6426565, 
            0.64265783, 0.64265933, 0.64266083, 0.6426625, 0.6426645, 0.64266667, 
            0.64266867, 0.64266967, 0.64267133, 0.64267333, 0.6426755, 0.6426775, 
            0.64268, 0.64268317, 0.642685, 0.64268667, 0.64268817, 0.64268967, 
            0.64269117, 0.6426935, 0.64269617, 0.642698, 0.6427, 0.6427015, 
            0.6427035, 0.64270533, 0.64270817, 0.64271133, 0.642714, 0.64271617, 
            0.64271833, 0.64272017, 0.64272283, 0.64272567, 0.64272767, 0.64272983, 
            0.64273183, 0.64273317, 0.642735, 0.64273717, 0.642739, 0.642741, 
            0.64274317, 0.64274533, 0.64274733, 0.64275, 0.64275217, 0.64275467, 
            0.64275733, 0.64275967, 0.642762, 0.6427645, 0.64276617, 0.642768, 
            0.64277017, 0.64277217, 0.642775, 0.64277783, 0.64278, 0.64278217, 
            0.64278467, 0.64278683, 0.6427895, 0.642792, 0.642794, 0.64279583, 
            0.64279717, 0.64279867, 0.6428, 0.64280217, 0.6428045, 0.64280667, 
            0.64280817, 0.64281, 0.64281167, 0.64281333, 0.64281567, 0.64281817, 
            0.6428205, 0.64282267, 0.642825, 0.64282633, 0.64282817, 0.64283067, 
            0.64283283, 0.64283517, 0.64283767, 0.64284017, 0.6428425, 0.6428455, 
            0.64284783, 0.64284967, 0.64285117, 0.64285317, 0.642855, 0.64285733, 
            0.64286067, 0.6428635, 0.642866, 0.64286883, 0.64287083, 0.64287317, 
            0.642875, 0.64287683, 0.6428785, 0.64288033, 0.64288183, 0.6428835, 
            0.642886, 0.64288883, 0.64289133, 0.64289367, 0.6428955, 0.64289767, 
            0.64290017, 0.642903, 0.6429055, 0.6429075, 0.64290867, 0.64290983, 
            0.64291067, 0.642911, 0.642911, 0.64291083, 0.64291067, 0.64291017, 
            0.64290983, 0.64290933, 0.642909, 0.64290883, 0.64290833, 0.64290767, 
            0.642907, 0.6429065, 0.64290633, 0.64290583, 0.64290567, 0.642905, 
            0.64290417, 0.64290333, 0.6429025, 0.6429015, 0.6429005, 0.6428995, 
            0.64289833, 0.64289717, 0.6428965, 0.64289567, 0.64289483, 0.642894, 
            0.642893, 0.64289217, 0.64289167, 0.64289133, 0.64289083, 0.64289033, 
            0.64288967, 0.64288933, 0.6428885, 0.642888, 0.6428875, 0.64288717, 
            0.64288667, 0.642887, 0.64288683, 0.642887, 0.642887, 0.6428865, 
            0.64288667, 0.64288667, 0.64288683, 0.642887, 0.64288733, 0.6428875, 
            0.6428875, 0.64288767, 0.642888), 
    lat = c(0.093232, 0.09323217, 
            0.09323217, 0.09323217, 0.09323217, 0.093232, 0.093232, 0.093232, 
            0.09323183, 0.09323183, 0.09323183, 0.09323183, 0.093232, 0.09323183, 
            0.09323183, 0.09323183, 0.093232, 0.09323217, 0.09323233, 0.093233, 
            0.0932335, 0.093234, 0.09323383, 0.0932335, 0.09323317, 0.09323283, 
            0.09323233, 0.093232, 0.09323183, 0.093232, 0.09323233, 0.09323233, 
            0.09323233, 0.093232, 0.0932315, 0.09323083, 0.09323033, 0.09323033, 
            0.09323033, 0.09323033, 0.09323, 0.09322967, 0.09322917, 0.093229, 
            0.09322917, 0.0932295, 0.0932295, 0.0932295, 0.09322933, 0.093229, 
            0.09322867, 0.09322883, 0.093229, 0.09322933, 0.0932295, 0.0932295, 
            0.09322933, 0.09322883, 0.09322833, 0.09322767, 0.0932275, 0.09322733, 
            0.09322717, 0.09322683, 0.09322633, 0.09322617, 0.0932255, 0.09322533, 
            0.09322533, 0.0932255, 0.09322533, 0.09322533, 0.09322483, 0.09322433, 
            0.09322383, 0.093224, 0.093224, 0.09322417, 0.09322383, 0.09322367, 
            0.09322283, 0.09322233, 0.09322267, 0.093223, 0.09322367, 0.09322367, 
            0.09322367, 0.093223, 0.09322217, 0.0932215, 0.0932215, 0.09322167, 
            0.093222, 0.09322217, 0.093222, 0.093222, 0.09322183, 0.09322217, 
            0.09322233, 0.09322217, 0.09322183, 0.09322117, 0.09322067, 0.09322083, 
            0.09322083, 0.09322067, 0.09322033, 0.09321967, 0.09321917, 0.093219, 
            0.09321883, 0.09321933, 0.09321933, 0.0932195, 0.09321933, 0.09321883, 
            0.093218, 0.0932175, 0.09321733, 0.0932175, 0.09321783, 0.09321767, 
            0.09321767, 0.09321717, 0.09321667, 0.0932165, 0.09321683, 0.09321683, 
            0.09321683, 0.0932165, 0.09321583, 0.09321533, 0.09321517, 0.09321517, 
            0.09321533, 0.093215, 0.09321483, 0.09321433, 0.09321417, 0.0932145, 
            0.09321483, 0.093215, 0.09321517, 0.093215, 0.0932145, 0.09321433, 
            0.0932145, 0.0932145, 0.0932145, 0.09321433, 0.093214, 0.09321383, 
            0.09321417, 0.09321433, 0.093215, 0.093215, 0.09321483, 0.0932145, 
            0.09321417, 0.093214, 0.09321433, 0.0932145, 0.09321433, 0.093214, 
            0.0932135, 0.09321317, 0.09321333, 0.09321367, 0.093214, 0.093214, 
            0.09321383, 0.09321317, 0.09321267, 0.09321283, 0.09321267, 0.093213, 
            0.09321233, 0.0932125, 0.09321267, 0.09321283, 0.09321317, 0.09321367, 
            0.093214, 0.09321417, 0.09321383, 0.09321317, 0.09321267, 0.0932125, 
            0.0932125, 0.09321267, 0.09321283, 0.09321283, 0.09321267, 0.09321233, 
            0.093212, 0.09321183, 0.09321167, 0.0932115, 0.0932115, 0.09321117, 
            0.09321117, 0.09321117, 0.09321167, 0.093212, 0.09321183, 0.0932115, 
            0.09321133, 0.09321133, 0.09321183, 0.09321183, 0.093212, 0.0932115, 
            0.093211, 0.09321033, 0.09321017, 0.09321017, 0.09321017, 0.09321033, 
            0.09321033, 0.09321033, 0.09320967, 0.09320917, 0.09320867, 0.09320883, 
            0.09320867, 0.093209, 0.09320933, 0.093209, 0.09320883, 0.0932085, 
            0.09320817, 0.093208, 0.09320817, 0.09320817, 0.0932085, 0.0932085, 
            0.09320833, 0.09320783, 0.09320767, 0.09320767, 0.0932075, 0.09320783, 
            0.0932075, 0.09320733, 0.0932065, 0.09320583, 0.09320533, 0.093205, 
            0.09320467, 0.0932045, 0.093204, 0.09320367, 0.09320333, 0.09320333, 
            0.09320367, 0.09320433, 0.09320533, 0.09320683, 0.0932085, 0.09320983, 
            0.09321067, 0.0932115, 0.09321233, 0.09321333, 0.09321417, 0.093215, 
            0.09321633, 0.09321717, 0.09321767, 0.09321783, 0.09321817, 0.0932185, 
            0.09321933, 0.09322033, 0.09322117, 0.093222, 0.09322267, 0.0932235, 
            0.09322467, 0.09322517, 0.09322633, 0.09322683, 0.09322767, 0.09322817, 
            0.09322883, 0.0932295, 0.09323033, 0.09323067, 0.09323133, 0.09323133, 
            0.0932315, 0.0932315, 0.09323133, 0.09323183, 0.09323233, 0.09323333, 
            0.0932335, 0.093234, 0.09323333, 0.09323233, 0.0932315, 0.09323133, 
            0.09323133, 0.093232, 0.093232, 0.0932325, 0.09323233, 0.09323217, 
            0.09323183, 0.09323167, 0.09323117, 0.0932305, 0.09323017, 0.09323017, 
            0.09322967, 0.093229, 0.09322783, 0.09322683, 0.09322567, 0.09322433, 
            0.09322367, 0.09322283, 0.09322183, 0.09322083, 0.09322033, 0.09321967, 
            0.09321867, 0.09321817, 0.09321767, 0.09321733, 0.09321733, 0.09321717, 
            0.09321667, 0.09321617, 0.09321533, 0.09321533, 0.09321517, 0.09321567, 
            0.09321617, 0.0932165, 0.09321617, 0.093216, 0.09321617, 0.09321633, 
            0.09321733, 0.093218, 0.09321817, 0.09321833, 0.09321833, 0.09321883, 
            0.09321917, 0.09322, 0.093221, 0.093222, 0.09322267, 0.093223, 
            0.09322317, 0.09322383, 0.093224, 0.093225, 0.0932265, 0.09322767, 
            0.0932285, 0.09322883, 0.0932295, 0.09323, 0.093231, 0.09323233, 
            0.09323367, 0.09323483, 0.093236, 0.09323683, 0.09323733, 0.093237, 
            0.0932365, 0.09323633, 0.09323617, 0.09323617, 0.09323617, 0.09323583, 
            0.09323567, 0.0932355, 0.09323567, 0.09323617, 0.093237, 0.093237, 
            0.09323717, 0.093237, 0.09323683, 0.09323633, 0.09323633, 0.09323633, 
            0.09323633, 0.09323633, 0.09323617, 0.09323583, 0.09323533, 0.09323533, 
            0.093236, 0.09323683, 0.093237, 0.09323733, 0.09323717, 0.0932375, 
            0.09323767, 0.093238, 0.09323817, 0.09323867, 0.0932385, 0.0932385, 
            0.09323767, 0.09323733, 0.09323717, 0.09323733, 0.09323767, 0.09323733, 
            0.0932375, 0.09323683, 0.09323667, 0.093236, 0.093236, 0.093236, 
            0.09323583, 0.09323583, 0.09323533, 0.09323483, 0.09323417, 0.09323417, 
            0.09323417, 0.09323417, 0.09323383, 0.09323317, 0.09323283, 0.09323283, 
            0.09323283, 0.09323317, 0.093233, 0.09323283, 0.093232, 0.09323133, 
            0.09323067, 0.09323083, 0.093231, 0.0932315, 0.09323167, 0.09323183, 
            0.09323167, 0.0932315, 0.0932315, 0.0932315, 0.0932315, 0.0932315, 
            0.09323133, 0.093231, 0.0932305, 0.09323, 0.09322983, 0.09322983, 
            0.09323, 0.09322967, 0.09322933, 0.093229, 0.093229, 0.093229, 
            0.09322933, 0.09322917, 0.09322933, 0.09322883, 0.09322817, 0.093228, 
            0.09322817, 0.09322833, 0.09322867, 0.0932285, 0.0932285, 0.09322833, 
            0.093228, 0.093228, 0.09322817, 0.09322833, 0.0932285, 0.09322833, 
            0.09322817, 0.0932275, 0.09322733, 0.09322717, 0.09322733, 0.09322767, 
            0.0932275, 0.09322717, 0.09322683, 0.09322667, 0.09322667, 0.0932265, 
            0.0932265, 0.093226, 0.09322567, 0.09322483, 0.09322467, 0.09322467, 
            0.09322483, 0.09322517, 0.09322517, 0.09322517, 0.09322483, 0.09322433, 
            0.09322417, 0.09322417, 0.09322433, 0.09322417, 0.09322367, 0.09322333, 
            0.09322333, 0.09322333, 0.09322367, 0.0932235, 0.0932235, 0.093223, 
            0.09322233, 0.09322233, 0.09322233, 0.09322267, 0.09322317, 0.09322333, 
            0.09322333, 0.09322317, 0.09322283, 0.09322267, 0.09322283, 0.09322283, 
            0.09322317, 0.09322317, 0.09322317, 0.09322283, 0.09322283, 0.09322317, 
            0.0932235, 0.09322383, 0.09322367, 0.09322367, 0.09322317, 0.09322283, 
            0.093223, 0.093223, 0.09322317, 0.09322317, 0.093223, 0.09322233, 
            0.09322167, 0.09322167, 0.0932215, 0.09322183, 0.09322217, 0.09322233, 
            0.09322233, 0.09322183, 0.09322117, 0.09322083, 0.09322083, 0.09322067, 
            0.09322083, 0.093221, 0.093221, 0.09322033, 0.09322017, 0.09322033, 
            0.09322033, 0.09322083, 0.0932205, 0.09322067, 0.09322, 0.09321983, 
            0.09321983, 0.09322017, 0.09322067, 0.09322033, 0.0932205, 0.09321983, 
            0.09321967, 0.09322, 0.09322033, 0.09322033, 0.09321983, 0.09321967, 
            0.09321967, 0.09322, 0.09322017, 0.09322, 0.09321983, 0.0932195, 
            0.0932195, 0.09321967, 0.09321967, 0.09321967, 0.09321933, 0.093219, 
            0.09321883, 0.093219, 0.093219, 0.093219, 0.09321883, 0.09321883, 
            0.09321883, 0.09321917, 0.0932195, 0.0932195, 0.09321933, 0.093219, 
            0.093219, 0.09321917, 0.0932195, 0.0932195, 0.09321933, 0.09321917, 
            0.09321883, 0.09321917, 0.09321933, 0.09321983, 0.09321983, 0.09322, 
            0.09321983, 0.09321967, 0.09321967, 0.09321983, 0.09321983, 0.09321983, 
            0.09321967, 0.09321933, 0.0932195, 0.09321967, 0.09321983, 0.0932195, 
            0.0932195, 0.09321917, 0.09321883, 0.09321883, 0.09321883, 0.09321883, 
            0.09321883, 0.09321867, 0.09321867, 0.09321867, 0.09321867, 0.093219, 
            0.093219, 0.09321917, 0.09321917, 0.09321917, 0.09321967, 0.09321967, 
            0.09321933, 0.09321933, 0.093219, 0.09321917, 0.09321933, 0.09321967, 
            0.09321967, 0.09321967, 0.09321933, 0.09321917, 0.093219, 0.09321933, 
            0.09321983, 0.0932205, 0.093221, 0.09322167, 0.09322283, 0.0932245, 
            0.09322683, 0.09322933, 0.093232, 0.09323483, 0.0932375, 0.09324017, 
            0.09324283, 0.093245, 0.09324683, 0.0932485, 0.0932505, 0.09325183, 
            0.093254, 0.0932565, 0.0932585, 0.0932605, 0.09326283, 0.093265, 
            0.09326717, 0.09326983, 0.093272, 0.09327417, 0.09327617, 0.09327833, 
            0.09328017, 0.09328267, 0.09328533, 0.0932875, 0.0932895, 0.09329133, 
            0.09329317, 0.09329567, 0.09329783, 0.0933, 0.093302, 0.093304, 
            0.09330583, 0.09330817, 0.09331017, 0.09331183, 0.09331317, 0.0933145, 
            0.09331567, 0.09331683, 0.09331833, 0.093319, 0.0933195, 0.09331967, 
            0.09331983, 0.09331983, 0.09331967, 0.09331967, 0.09332, 0.09332, 
            0.09332, 0.09331983, 0.09331967, 0.0933195, 0.09331933, 0.09331933
    )
  ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -728L))
```

```r
# Visual aid
base_plot <- 
  ggplot(anon_track, aes(lng, lat)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_equal()
base_plot
```

[image]

```r
# Attempt 1: kernel density estimate
n_kde <- 
  c(diff(range(anon_track$lng)), diff(range(anon_track$lat))) %>% 
  {ceiling(50*./max(.))}
anon_kde <- MASS::kde2d(anon_track$lng, anon_track$lat, n = n_kde)
kde_max_idx <- which(anon_kde$z > quantile(anon_kde$z, 0.95), arr.ind = T)

# Visual pattern of the density estimate
kde_plot <- 
  expand.grid(lng = anon_kde$x, lat = anon_kde$y) %>% 
  mutate(z = as.vector(anon_kde$z)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lng, lat, color = z)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 15) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_color_viridis_c()

# Top 95% of locations overlaid on track
kde_track <- 
  ggplot(anon_track, aes(lng, lat)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(
    geom = "point",
    x = anon_kde$x[kde_max_idx[,1]],
    y = anon_kde$y[kde_max_idx[,2]],
    size = 5, shape = 0
    ) +
  coord_equal()

kde_plot / kde_track
```

[image]

```r
# Attempt 2: rolling distance covered
d2 <- function(x, y, n) {
  x_min <- RcppRoll::roll_min(x, n, fill = NA)
  x_max <- RcppRoll::roll_max(x, n, fill = NA)
  
  y_min <- RcppRoll::roll_min(y, n, fill = NA)
  y_max <- RcppRoll::roll_max(y, n, fill = NA)
  
  (x_max - x_min)^2 + (y_max - y_min)^2
}

anon_dists <- 
  anon_track %>% 
  mutate(
    d = sqrt(d2(lng, lat, 20)),
    flag = d > RcppRoll::roll_min(d, 50, fill = NA)
  )

d20_plot <- 
  anon_dists %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ts, d)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(
    data = function(x) filter(x, !flag),
    size = 5, shape = 0
  )


{
  base_plot +
    geom_point(
      data = filter(anon_dists, !flag),
      size = 5, shape = 0
    )
  } / d20_plot +
  plot_layout(heights = c(.33, .67))
```

[image]

```r
# Attempt 3: directional changes
anon_headings <- 
  anon_track %>% 
  mutate(
    h = geosphere::bearing(
      matrix(c(lng, lat), ncol = 2), 
      matrix(c(lead(lng), lead(lat)), ncol = 2)
    ),
    delta_h = lead(h, 2) - h
    # heading change over 3 points to smooth out noise
  )

# get the top changes in heading to find turn-around
heading_change <- 
  anon_headings %>% 
  arrange(desc(abs(delta_h))) %>% 
  slice(1:3)

headings_plot <- 
  anon_headings %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ts, delta_h)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(
    data = heading_change,
    shape = 0, size = 5
  )

{
  base_plot +
  geom_point(
    data = heading_change,
    size = 5, shape = 0
  )
} /  headings_plot +
  plot_layout(heights = c(.33, .67))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried an altogether different approach that has a few assumptions attached, but I think will be most robust in this case.

I'm now assuming that the user makes exactly (or almost exactly) one crossing of their own path at the area of interest, and that the loop diameter is much larger than the step size along the transect.

Given this, I used a properly geospatial approach instead of trying to DIY an algorithm. I convert the points to a line, find where the line crosses itself, and attempt to convert each section into a closed polygon.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# Example data
# anon_track <- read.csv("anon_track.csv")
# dput(anon_track)
anon_track <- structure(
  list(
    ts = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
           10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
           23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
           36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
           49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 
           62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 
           75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
           88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
           101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
           112L, 113L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
           113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 
           124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 
           135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 
           146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
           157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 
           168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 
           179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 
           190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 
           201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 
           212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 
           223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 
           234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 
           245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 
           256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 
           267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 
           278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 
           289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 
           300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 
           311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 
           322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 
           333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 
           344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 
           355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 
           366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 
           377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 386L, 387L, 
           388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 
           399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 
           410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 
           421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 431L, 
           432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 442L, 
           443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 
           454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 
           465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 474L, 475L, 
           476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 486L, 
           487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 
           498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 
           509L, 510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 518L, 519L, 
           520L, 521L, 522L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 
           531L, 532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 541L, 
           542L, 543L, 544L, 545L, 546L, 547L, 548L, 549L, 550L, 551L, 552L, 
           553L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 560L, 561L, 562L, 563L, 
           564L, 565L, 566L, 567L, 568L, 569L, 570L, 571L, 572L, 573L, 574L, 
           575L, 576L, 577L, 578L, 579L, 580L, 581L, 582L, 583L, 584L, 585L, 
           586L, 587L, 588L, 589L, 590L, 591L, 592L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 
           597L, 598L, 599L, 600L, 601L, 602L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 606L, 607L, 
           608L, 609L, 610L, 611L, 612L, 613L, 614L, 615L, 616L, 617L, 618L, 
           619L, 620L, 621L, 622L, 623L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L, 
           630L, 631L, 632L, 633L, 634L, 635L, 636L, 637L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 
           641L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 
           652L, 653L, 654L, 655L, 656L, 657L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 661L, 662L, 
           663L, 664L, 665L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 671L, 672L, 673L, 
           674L, 675L, 676L, 677L, 678L, 679L, 680L, 681L, 682L, 683L, 684L, 
           685L, 686L, 687L, 688L, 689L, 690L, 691L, 692L, 693L, 694L, 695L, 
           696L, 697L, 698L, 699L, 700L, 701L, 702L, 703L, 704L, 705L, 706L, 
           707L, 708L, 709L, 710L, 711L, 712L, 713L, 714L, 715L, 716L, 717L
    ), 
    lng = c(0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.64187717, 
            0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.64187717, 0.6418775, 0.64187733, 
            0.64187733, 0.64187717, 0.641877, 0.641877, 0.64187633, 0.6418755, 
            0.64187533, 0.64187533, 0.64187517, 0.64187567, 0.64187617, 0.64187717, 
            0.64187817, 0.64187917, 0.64188033, 0.64188167, 0.64188317, 0.6418845, 
            0.641886, 0.64188767, 0.64188933, 0.64189067, 0.64189217, 0.64189367, 
            0.6418955, 0.64189783, 0.64189967, 0.64190217, 0.6419045, 0.64190683, 
            0.64190867, 0.64191083, 0.64191283, 0.64191467, 0.641917, 0.64191917, 
            0.641921, 0.64192267, 0.6419245, 0.641927, 0.64192917, 0.641931, 
            0.641933, 0.64193433, 0.64193567, 0.64193683, 0.6419385, 0.6419405, 
            0.64194283, 0.64194517, 0.641947, 0.641949, 0.64195083, 0.64195233, 
            0.64195333, 0.641955, 0.64195717, 0.6419595, 0.64196167, 0.64196417, 
            0.641966, 0.641968, 0.64196983, 0.6419725, 0.64197417, 0.641976, 
            0.64197733, 0.641979, 0.64198033, 0.6419825, 0.64198533, 0.64198733, 
            0.64198933, 0.64199083, 0.64199233, 0.64199333, 0.64199483, 0.64199667, 
            0.64199883, 0.6420005, 0.64200267, 0.64200483, 0.642007, 0.64200933, 
            0.6420115, 0.64201367, 0.64201533, 0.64201683, 0.64201833, 0.64201967, 
            0.64202133, 0.64202317, 0.64202467, 0.6420265, 0.64202867, 0.64203017, 
            0.64203167, 0.64203333, 0.642035, 0.6420365, 0.64203817, 0.64204033, 
            0.64204217, 0.64204383, 0.6420455, 0.64204833, 0.642051, 0.64205333, 
            0.64205517, 0.64205717, 0.64205867, 0.64206017, 0.64206233, 0.64206517, 
            0.642068, 0.6420705, 0.64207283, 0.64207483, 0.642077, 0.64207933, 
            0.642082, 0.64208417, 0.64208633, 0.64208867, 0.64209083, 0.64209267, 
            0.64209517, 0.64209767, 0.6421, 0.64210217, 0.642104, 0.64210583, 
            0.64210783, 0.64211017, 0.6421125, 0.6421145, 0.64211683, 0.6421185, 
            0.642121, 0.64212317, 0.64212617, 0.64212783, 0.64213033, 0.64213217, 
            0.64213383, 0.6421345, 0.642136, 0.642138, 0.64214033, 0.64214167, 
            0.64214317, 0.64214433, 0.64214567, 0.64214717, 0.64214917, 0.64215117, 
            0.6421535, 0.64215583, 0.642158, 0.64216033, 0.64216217, 0.64216483, 
            0.64216633, 0.64216833, 0.64217067, 0.64217367, 0.64217533, 0.64217767, 
            0.6421795, 0.64218133, 0.64218233, 0.6421835, 0.6421845, 0.6421865, 
            0.6421885, 0.64219083, 0.6421925, 0.64219367, 0.64219533, 0.64219767, 
            0.64219967, 0.64220183, 0.64220467, 0.6422075, 0.64220917, 0.64221117, 
            0.642213, 0.64221467, 0.64221683, 0.6422195, 0.64222233, 0.64222433, 
            0.6422265, 0.6422285, 0.64223033, 0.64223317, 0.6422355, 0.64223717, 
            0.642239, 0.64224067, 0.6422415, 0.6422425, 0.642244, 0.64224617, 
            0.64224783, 0.6422495, 0.64225117, 0.64225317, 0.6422545, 0.64225617, 
            0.64225817, 0.64226067, 0.64226233, 0.64226383, 0.64226517, 0.6422665, 
            0.6422675, 0.642268, 0.64226967, 0.6422715, 0.6422735, 0.64227533, 
            0.64227733, 0.64227917, 0.64228083, 0.6422825, 0.642285, 0.64228767, 
            0.64228917, 0.64229083, 0.6422925, 0.642294, 0.6422955, 0.64229783, 
            0.64230067, 0.642303, 0.6423045, 0.64230617, 0.64230783, 0.64230917, 
            0.64231033, 0.642312, 0.64231383, 0.64231533, 0.642317, 0.6423185, 
            0.64231983, 0.64232067, 0.64232117, 0.64232167, 0.642322, 0.642323, 
            0.64232367, 0.6423245, 0.64232583, 0.6423265, 0.64232683, 0.64232667, 
            0.64232667, 0.642327, 0.642328, 0.64232917, 0.642331, 0.6423325, 
            0.64233333, 0.6423335, 0.64233333, 0.642333, 0.64233383, 0.64233467, 
            0.64233633, 0.64233817, 0.64234033, 0.6423415, 0.6423425, 0.64234317, 
            0.64234383, 0.64234417, 0.6423455, 0.6423475, 0.64234933, 0.64235083, 
            0.64235183, 0.642353, 0.642354, 0.64235517, 0.642356, 0.64235733, 
            0.64235933, 0.64236133, 0.642363, 0.64236433, 0.6423655, 0.64236617, 
            0.64236667, 0.642367, 0.6423675, 0.64236833, 0.64236933, 0.64237067, 
            0.64237183, 0.64237267, 0.64237317, 0.642373, 0.64237283, 0.64237233, 
            0.64237283, 0.64237317, 0.6423735, 0.64237317, 0.64237283, 0.64237233, 
            0.64237133, 0.6423715, 0.6423715, 0.64237183, 0.64237133, 0.64237117, 
            0.64237033, 0.6423695, 0.64236833, 0.64236733, 0.64236633, 0.6423655, 
            0.64236433, 0.64236283, 0.64236083, 0.6423585, 0.642357, 0.64235533, 
            0.64235417, 0.64235267, 0.642351, 0.64234933, 0.64234767, 0.64234667, 
            0.64234567, 0.6423445, 0.64234367, 0.64234267, 0.642342, 0.64234133, 
            0.64234083, 0.64234, 0.64233933, 0.64233867, 0.64233817, 0.6423375, 
            0.6423375, 0.64233767, 0.64233733, 0.64233733, 0.64233683, 0.64233683, 
            0.642337, 0.64233817, 0.6423395, 0.64234033, 0.64234017, 0.64234067, 
            0.642341, 0.64234083, 0.64234083, 0.64234117, 0.64234267, 0.6423435, 
            0.6423445, 0.64234567, 0.6423465, 0.64234767, 0.64234983, 0.6423515, 
            0.64235267, 0.64235383, 0.64235533, 0.642356, 0.642357, 0.64235817, 
            0.64235967, 0.64236083, 0.64236217, 0.64236433, 0.64236717, 0.6423695, 
            0.64237167, 0.64237417, 0.64237667, 0.6423785, 0.64238017, 0.64238183, 
            0.64238333, 0.6423855, 0.64238767, 0.64239017, 0.642392, 0.64239367, 
            0.6423945, 0.642396, 0.64239667, 0.64239867, 0.642401, 0.64240283, 
            0.64240417, 0.64240567, 0.64240767, 0.64240917, 0.642411, 0.64241267, 
            0.64241417, 0.6424155, 0.6424175, 0.642419, 0.64242, 0.64242167, 
            0.64242383, 0.6424265, 0.64242867, 0.642431, 0.6424335, 0.64243567, 
            0.64243767, 0.64244, 0.642442, 0.64244433, 0.64244583, 0.642447, 
            0.64244733, 0.6424485, 0.64245033, 0.64245283, 0.64245433, 0.64245617, 
            0.64245783, 0.64245967, 0.642461, 0.64246283, 0.642465, 0.64246733, 
            0.64246933, 0.64247083, 0.64247233, 0.64247383, 0.64247533, 0.64247733, 
            0.64247967, 0.6424815, 0.64248317, 0.64248467, 0.6424865, 0.64248833, 
            0.642491, 0.642493, 0.64249433, 0.64249567, 0.64249733, 0.6424985, 
            0.6425005, 0.642503, 0.64250583, 0.642508, 0.64251, 0.6425115, 
            0.64251333, 0.64251483, 0.64251717, 0.64252017, 0.64252233, 0.64252417, 
            0.64252617, 0.64252833, 0.64253017, 0.64253233, 0.642535, 0.64253717, 
            0.64253883, 0.64254067, 0.64254267, 0.642545, 0.64254683, 0.64254917, 
            0.6425515, 0.64255283, 0.6425545, 0.642556, 0.64255767, 0.64255917, 
            0.64256117, 0.642563, 0.64256467, 0.64256633, 0.64256817, 0.64257, 
            0.6425715, 0.6425735, 0.64257583, 0.64257733, 0.64257883, 0.64258083, 
            0.64258267, 0.64258467, 0.64258733, 0.64258917, 0.64259083, 0.64259233, 
            0.642594, 0.64259517, 0.64259683, 0.64259917, 0.642601, 0.64260267, 
            0.642604, 0.64260517, 0.6426065, 0.6426075, 0.6426095, 0.642612, 
            0.64261467, 0.64261667, 0.64261833, 0.64262, 0.6426215, 0.64262333, 
            0.64262567, 0.6426285, 0.6426305, 0.6426325, 0.64263383, 0.64263583, 
            0.64263783, 0.6426405, 0.64264333, 0.64264517, 0.64264667, 0.64264767, 
            0.64264883, 0.64265, 0.64265167, 0.64265367, 0.642655, 0.6426565, 
            0.64265783, 0.64265933, 0.64266083, 0.6426625, 0.6426645, 0.64266667, 
            0.64266867, 0.64266967, 0.64267133, 0.64267333, 0.6426755, 0.6426775, 
            0.64268, 0.64268317, 0.642685, 0.64268667, 0.64268817, 0.64268967, 
            0.64269117, 0.6426935, 0.64269617, 0.642698, 0.6427, 0.6427015, 
            0.6427035, 0.64270533, 0.64270817, 0.64271133, 0.642714, 0.64271617, 
            0.64271833, 0.64272017, 0.64272283, 0.64272567, 0.64272767, 0.64272983, 
            0.64273183, 0.64273317, 0.642735, 0.64273717, 0.642739, 0.642741, 
            0.64274317, 0.64274533, 0.64274733, 0.64275, 0.64275217, 0.64275467, 
            0.64275733, 0.64275967, 0.642762, 0.6427645, 0.64276617, 0.642768, 
            0.64277017, 0.64277217, 0.642775, 0.64277783, 0.64278, 0.64278217, 
            0.64278467, 0.64278683, 0.6427895, 0.642792, 0.642794, 0.64279583, 
            0.64279717, 0.64279867, 0.6428, 0.64280217, 0.6428045, 0.64280667, 
            0.64280817, 0.64281, 0.64281167, 0.64281333, 0.64281567, 0.64281817, 
            0.6428205, 0.64282267, 0.642825, 0.64282633, 0.64282817, 0.64283067, 
            0.64283283, 0.64283517, 0.64283767, 0.64284017, 0.6428425, 0.6428455, 
            0.64284783, 0.64284967, 0.64285117, 0.64285317, 0.642855, 0.64285733, 
            0.64286067, 0.6428635, 0.642866, 0.64286883, 0.64287083, 0.64287317, 
            0.642875, 0.64287683, 0.6428785, 0.64288033, 0.64288183, 0.6428835, 
            0.642886, 0.64288883, 0.64289133, 0.64289367, 0.6428955, 0.64289767, 
            0.64290017, 0.642903, 0.6429055, 0.6429075, 0.64290867, 0.64290983, 
            0.64291067, 0.642911, 0.642911, 0.64291083, 0.64291067, 0.64291017, 
            0.64290983, 0.64290933, 0.642909, 0.64290883, 0.64290833, 0.64290767, 
            0.642907, 0.6429065, 0.64290633, 0.64290583, 0.64290567, 0.642905, 
            0.64290417, 0.64290333, 0.6429025, 0.6429015, 0.6429005, 0.6428995, 
            0.64289833, 0.64289717, 0.6428965, 0.64289567, 0.64289483, 0.642894, 
            0.642893, 0.64289217, 0.64289167, 0.64289133, 0.64289083, 0.64289033, 
            0.64288967, 0.64288933, 0.6428885, 0.642888, 0.6428875, 0.64288717, 
            0.64288667, 0.642887, 0.64288683, 0.642887, 0.642887, 0.6428865, 
            0.64288667, 0.64288667, 0.64288683, 0.642887, 0.64288733, 0.6428875, 
            0.6428875, 0.64288767, 0.642888), 
    lat = c(0.093232, 0.09323217, 
            0.09323217, 0.09323217, 0.09323217, 0.093232, 0.093232, 0.093232, 
            0.09323183, 0.09323183, 0.09323183, 0.09323183, 0.093232, 0.09323183, 
            0.09323183, 0.09323183, 0.093232, 0.09323217, 0.09323233, 0.093233, 
            0.0932335, 0.093234, 0.09323383, 0.0932335, 0.09323317, 0.09323283, 
            0.09323233, 0.093232, 0.09323183, 0.093232, 0.09323233, 0.09323233, 
            0.09323233, 0.093232, 0.0932315, 0.09323083, 0.09323033, 0.09323033, 
            0.09323033, 0.09323033, 0.09323, 0.09322967, 0.09322917, 0.093229, 
            0.09322917, 0.0932295, 0.0932295, 0.0932295, 0.09322933, 0.093229, 
            0.09322867, 0.09322883, 0.093229, 0.09322933, 0.0932295, 0.0932295, 
            0.09322933, 0.09322883, 0.09322833, 0.09322767, 0.0932275, 0.09322733, 
            0.09322717, 0.09322683, 0.09322633, 0.09322617, 0.0932255, 0.09322533, 
            0.09322533, 0.0932255, 0.09322533, 0.09322533, 0.09322483, 0.09322433, 
            0.09322383, 0.093224, 0.093224, 0.09322417, 0.09322383, 0.09322367, 
            0.09322283, 0.09322233, 0.09322267, 0.093223, 0.09322367, 0.09322367, 
            0.09322367, 0.093223, 0.09322217, 0.0932215, 0.0932215, 0.09322167, 
            0.093222, 0.09322217, 0.093222, 0.093222, 0.09322183, 0.09322217, 
            0.09322233, 0.09322217, 0.09322183, 0.09322117, 0.09322067, 0.09322083, 
            0.09322083, 0.09322067, 0.09322033, 0.09321967, 0.09321917, 0.093219, 
            0.09321883, 0.09321933, 0.09321933, 0.0932195, 0.09321933, 0.09321883, 
            0.093218, 0.0932175, 0.09321733, 0.0932175, 0.09321783, 0.09321767, 
            0.09321767, 0.09321717, 0.09321667, 0.0932165, 0.09321683, 0.09321683, 
            0.09321683, 0.0932165, 0.09321583, 0.09321533, 0.09321517, 0.09321517, 
            0.09321533, 0.093215, 0.09321483, 0.09321433, 0.09321417, 0.0932145, 
            0.09321483, 0.093215, 0.09321517, 0.093215, 0.0932145, 0.09321433, 
            0.0932145, 0.0932145, 0.0932145, 0.09321433, 0.093214, 0.09321383, 
            0.09321417, 0.09321433, 0.093215, 0.093215, 0.09321483, 0.0932145, 
            0.09321417, 0.093214, 0.09321433, 0.0932145, 0.09321433, 0.093214, 
            0.0932135, 0.09321317, 0.09321333, 0.09321367, 0.093214, 0.093214, 
            0.09321383, 0.09321317, 0.09321267, 0.09321283, 0.09321267, 0.093213, 
            0.09321233, 0.0932125, 0.09321267, 0.09321283, 0.09321317, 0.09321367, 
            0.093214, 0.09321417, 0.09321383, 0.09321317, 0.09321267, 0.0932125, 
            0.0932125, 0.09321267, 0.09321283, 0.09321283, 0.09321267, 0.09321233, 
            0.093212, 0.09321183, 0.09321167, 0.0932115, 0.0932115, 0.09321117, 
            0.09321117, 0.09321117, 0.09321167, 0.093212, 0.09321183, 0.0932115, 
            0.09321133, 0.09321133, 0.09321183, 0.09321183, 0.093212, 0.0932115, 
            0.093211, 0.09321033, 0.09321017, 0.09321017, 0.09321017, 0.09321033, 
            0.09321033, 0.09321033, 0.09320967, 0.09320917, 0.09320867, 0.09320883, 
            0.09320867, 0.093209, 0.09320933, 0.093209, 0.09320883, 0.0932085, 
            0.09320817, 0.093208, 0.09320817, 0.09320817, 0.0932085, 0.0932085, 
            0.09320833, 0.09320783, 0.09320767, 0.09320767, 0.0932075, 0.09320783, 
            0.0932075, 0.09320733, 0.0932065, 0.09320583, 0.09320533, 0.093205, 
            0.09320467, 0.0932045, 0.093204, 0.09320367, 0.09320333, 0.09320333, 
            0.09320367, 0.09320433, 0.09320533, 0.09320683, 0.0932085, 0.09320983, 
            0.09321067, 0.0932115, 0.09321233, 0.09321333, 0.09321417, 0.093215, 
            0.09321633, 0.09321717, 0.09321767, 0.09321783, 0.09321817, 0.0932185, 
            0.09321933, 0.09322033, 0.09322117, 0.093222, 0.09322267, 0.0932235, 
            0.09322467, 0.09322517, 0.09322633, 0.09322683, 0.09322767, 0.09322817, 
            0.09322883, 0.0932295, 0.09323033, 0.09323067, 0.09323133, 0.09323133, 
            0.0932315, 0.0932315, 0.09323133, 0.09323183, 0.09323233, 0.09323333, 
            0.0932335, 0.093234, 0.09323333, 0.09323233, 0.0932315, 0.09323133, 
            0.09323133, 0.093232, 0.093232, 0.0932325, 0.09323233, 0.09323217, 
            0.09323183, 0.09323167, 0.09323117, 0.0932305, 0.09323017, 0.09323017, 
            0.09322967, 0.093229, 0.09322783, 0.09322683, 0.09322567, 0.09322433, 
            0.09322367, 0.09322283, 0.09322183, 0.09322083, 0.09322033, 0.09321967, 
            0.09321867, 0.09321817, 0.09321767, 0.09321733, 0.09321733, 0.09321717, 
            0.09321667, 0.09321617, 0.09321533, 0.09321533, 0.09321517, 0.09321567, 
            0.09321617, 0.0932165, 0.09321617, 0.093216, 0.09321617, 0.09321633, 
            0.09321733, 0.093218, 0.09321817, 0.09321833, 0.09321833, 0.09321883, 
            0.09321917, 0.09322, 0.093221, 0.093222, 0.09322267, 0.093223, 
            0.09322317, 0.09322383, 0.093224, 0.093225, 0.0932265, 0.09322767, 
            0.0932285, 0.09322883, 0.0932295, 0.09323, 0.093231, 0.09323233, 
            0.09323367, 0.09323483, 0.093236, 0.09323683, 0.09323733, 0.093237, 
            0.0932365, 0.09323633, 0.09323617, 0.09323617, 0.09323617, 0.09323583, 
            0.09323567, 0.0932355, 0.09323567, 0.09323617, 0.093237, 0.093237, 
            0.09323717, 0.093237, 0.09323683, 0.09323633, 0.09323633, 0.09323633, 
            0.09323633, 0.09323633, 0.09323617, 0.09323583, 0.09323533, 0.09323533, 
            0.093236, 0.09323683, 0.093237, 0.09323733, 0.09323717, 0.0932375, 
            0.09323767, 0.093238, 0.09323817, 0.09323867, 0.0932385, 0.0932385, 
            0.09323767, 0.09323733, 0.09323717, 0.09323733, 0.09323767, 0.09323733, 
            0.0932375, 0.09323683, 0.09323667, 0.093236, 0.093236, 0.093236, 
            0.09323583, 0.09323583, 0.09323533, 0.09323483, 0.09323417, 0.09323417, 
            0.09323417, 0.09323417, 0.09323383, 0.09323317, 0.09323283, 0.09323283, 
            0.09323283, 0.09323317, 0.093233, 0.09323283, 0.093232, 0.09323133, 
            0.09323067, 0.09323083, 0.093231, 0.0932315, 0.09323167, 0.09323183, 
            0.09323167, 0.0932315, 0.0932315, 0.0932315, 0.0932315, 0.0932315, 
            0.09323133, 0.093231, 0.0932305, 0.09323, 0.09322983, 0.09322983, 
            0.09323, 0.09322967, 0.09322933, 0.093229, 0.093229, 0.093229, 
            0.09322933, 0.09322917, 0.09322933, 0.09322883, 0.09322817, 0.093228, 
            0.09322817, 0.09322833, 0.09322867, 0.0932285, 0.0932285, 0.09322833, 
            0.093228, 0.093228, 0.09322817, 0.09322833, 0.0932285, 0.09322833, 
            0.09322817, 0.0932275, 0.09322733, 0.09322717, 0.09322733, 0.09322767, 
            0.0932275, 0.09322717, 0.09322683, 0.09322667, 0.09322667, 0.0932265, 
            0.0932265, 0.093226, 0.09322567, 0.09322483, 0.09322467, 0.09322467, 
            0.09322483, 0.09322517, 0.09322517, 0.09322517, 0.09322483, 0.09322433, 
            0.09322417, 0.09322417, 0.09322433, 0.09322417, 0.09322367, 0.09322333, 
            0.09322333, 0.09322333, 0.09322367, 0.0932235, 0.0932235, 0.093223, 
            0.09322233, 0.09322233, 0.09322233, 0.09322267, 0.09322317, 0.09322333, 
            0.09322333, 0.09322317, 0.09322283, 0.09322267, 0.09322283, 0.09322283, 
            0.09322317, 0.09322317, 0.09322317, 0.09322283, 0.09322283, 0.09322317, 
            0.0932235, 0.09322383, 0.09322367, 0.09322367, 0.09322317, 0.09322283, 
            0.093223, 0.093223, 0.09322317, 0.09322317, 0.093223, 0.09322233, 
            0.09322167, 0.09322167, 0.0932215, 0.09322183, 0.09322217, 0.09322233, 
            0.09322233, 0.09322183, 0.09322117, 0.09322083, 0.09322083, 0.09322067, 
            0.09322083, 0.093221, 0.093221, 0.09322033, 0.09322017, 0.09322033, 
            0.09322033, 0.09322083, 0.0932205, 0.09322067, 0.09322, 0.09321983, 
            0.09321983, 0.09322017, 0.09322067, 0.09322033, 0.0932205, 0.09321983, 
            0.09321967, 0.09322, 0.09322033, 0.09322033, 0.09321983, 0.09321967, 
            0.09321967, 0.09322, 0.09322017, 0.09322, 0.09321983, 0.0932195, 
            0.0932195, 0.09321967, 0.09321967, 0.09321967, 0.09321933, 0.093219, 
            0.09321883, 0.093219, 0.093219, 0.093219, 0.09321883, 0.09321883, 
            0.09321883, 0.09321917, 0.0932195, 0.0932195, 0.09321933, 0.093219, 
            0.093219, 0.09321917, 0.0932195, 0.0932195, 0.09321933, 0.09321917, 
            0.09321883, 0.09321917, 0.09321933, 0.09321983, 0.09321983, 0.09322, 
            0.09321983, 0.09321967, 0.09321967, 0.09321983, 0.09321983, 0.09321983, 
            0.09321967, 0.09321933, 0.0932195, 0.09321967, 0.09321983, 0.0932195, 
            0.0932195, 0.09321917, 0.09321883, 0.09321883, 0.09321883, 0.09321883, 
            0.09321883, 0.09321867, 0.09321867, 0.09321867, 0.09321867, 0.093219, 
            0.093219, 0.09321917, 0.09321917, 0.09321917, 0.09321967, 0.09321967, 
            0.09321933, 0.09321933, 0.093219, 0.09321917, 0.09321933, 0.09321967, 
            0.09321967, 0.09321967, 0.09321933, 0.09321917, 0.093219, 0.09321933, 
            0.09321983, 0.0932205, 0.093221, 0.09322167, 0.09322283, 0.0932245, 
            0.09322683, 0.09322933, 0.093232, 0.09323483, 0.0932375, 0.09324017, 
            0.09324283, 0.093245, 0.09324683, 0.0932485, 0.0932505, 0.09325183, 
            0.093254, 0.0932565, 0.0932585, 0.0932605, 0.09326283, 0.093265, 
            0.09326717, 0.09326983, 0.093272, 0.09327417, 0.09327617, 0.09327833, 
            0.09328017, 0.09328267, 0.09328533, 0.0932875, 0.0932895, 0.09329133, 
            0.09329317, 0.09329567, 0.09329783, 0.0933, 0.093302, 0.093304, 
            0.09330583, 0.09330817, 0.09331017, 0.09331183, 0.09331317, 0.0933145, 
            0.09331567, 0.09331683, 0.09331833, 0.093319, 0.0933195, 0.09331967, 
            0.09331983, 0.09331983, 0.09331967, 0.09331967, 0.09332, 0.09332, 
            0.09332, 0.09331983, 0.09331967, 0.0933195, 0.09331933, 0.09331933
    )
  ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -728L))
```

```r
# Visual aid, now with sf
anon_track |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lng","lat"), crs = 4326) |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
# Zoom in on the area of interest
anon_track |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lng","lat"), crs = 4326) |> 
  slice(250:420) |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
# Convert points to a single LINESTRING
track_ls <- 
  anon_track |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lng","lat"), crs = 4326) |>
  st_combine() |> 
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

track_ls
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0.6418752 ymin: 0.09320333 xmax: 0.642911 ymax: 0.09332
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> LINESTRING (0.6418772 0.093232, 0.6418772 0.093...
```

```r
# Find intersection of track with itself,
#  resulting in 11 linestrings.
# Convert those into polygons if they form
#  closed loops, resulting in 4 objects.
track_polys <- 
  st_intersection(
    track_ls,
    track_ls
  ) |> 
  st_polygonize() |> 
  st_cast()

track_polys
#> Geometry set for 4 features 
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0.6418772 ymin: 0.09321517 xmax: 0.6428867 ymax: 0.09331972
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> POLYGON ((0.6418773 0.09323183, 0.6418772 0.093...
#> POLYGON ((0.6423374 0.09322733, 0.6423382 0.093...
#> POLYGON ((0.642341 0.09323678, 0.6423408 0.0932...
#> POLYGON ((0.6428867 0.09331972, 0.6428867 0.093...
```

```r
# Measure the area of each loop to ID the correct one.
#   I have to assume that very small loops are random noise,
#   and the intended marker is the largest.
track_poly_df <- 
  track_polys |> 
  st_as_sf(crs = 4326) |> 
  st_set_geometry("geometry") |> 
  mutate(
    size = st_area(geometry)
  ) |> 
  arrange(desc(size)) 

track_poly_df
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0.6418772 ymin: 0.09321517 xmax: 0.6428867 ymax: 0.09331972
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                 size                       geometry
#> 1 5.965397e+00 [m^2] POLYGON ((0.6423374 0.09322...
#> 2 4.209702e-04 [m^2] POLYGON ((0.642341 0.093236...
#> 3 1.681549e-04 [m^2] POLYGON ((0.6418773 0.09323...
#> 4 5.717268e-05 [m^2] POLYGON ((0.6428867 0.09331...
```

```r
# Plot alongside the original track (zoomed in)
track_poly_df |> 
  slice(1) |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(fill = "blue") +
  geom_sf(
    data = 
      anon_track |> 
      st_as_sf(coords = c("lng","lat"), crs = 4326) |> 
      slice(250:420)
    )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>